# Sending simple email via MacOs 12 Terminal with mail (mail_version = 3.2.2)

Tags: email, postfix-mta, macos-monterey

I would like my MacOS "server" (basic mac mini with OS12.1 installed)
to be able to send emails using my current (paid) email provider.

**Some theory first.**

- I am aware about this fine article (http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081217161612647)
- What puzzles me is how on earth will "fresh out of box" mac be able to send even ONE  email without being (mail-server) configured first. In other words to what email server will it send my email?
- Discovered the very useful command `mailq` that will show the current status of all current emails being processed.
- I understood that the command `mail` will send an email:

  `echo "this is the body" | mail -s "this is the subject" "myself@myserver.lu"`
- I understand, mail is using postfix in the background.
- This will show the version of postfix (mine is mail_version = 3.2.2)

  `postconf mail_version`
- Is it possible to update postfix on macos?
- Did anyone managed to enable the log on mail_version 3.2.2?
  I get this warning:

  `postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: maillog_file=/var/log/postfix.log`

without the log it is a bit difficult to see what went wrong during email send...

thanks in advance for some MAC related input.